# Nuxt - how to preserve store state when returning back to root (homepage)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

In Nuxt project I have some animations on homepage and I don't want them to run second time when user returns back to homepage for example from About page

So I have a variable in store -> index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  isVisited: false
})
```

and in index.vue if isVisited is false run animations and set variable to true

```
    if (this.$store.state.isVisited == false) {
      this.initialAnimation();
      this.$store.state.isVisited = true
    }
```

When I go to About page isVisited is true, so that works, but when I return back to / (homepage) isVisited is back to false and animations run again. Ok this is logical, store resets it self when page is reloaded on root but I don't have ideas how to tackle this problem differently.

Another idea I had was to detect if user comes from /about page and then turn off the animations, but the problem then is that user could land on about page first and he will never saw initial home animations, and we don't want that.

I'm new to store / vuex stuff and I don't understand it clearly yet, so sorry if the question is noobish

Comment: store reset itself when u do reload on any page. E.g. when u load page from server, not when u navigate withing app.

Comment: @Aldarund thanks. Yes when I navigate within app store is ok, only when I return to "/" store reset itself. Do you have idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How you return to / ? You should use nuxt-link for going to / and then it wont be lost till user hit actual page reload button

Comment: If you directly go to '/' from the browser than it is a server-side request. so your vuex store will not persist.

Comment: @Aldarund yes nuxt-link is a solution. I used router-link in pure vue, but I somehow completely missed nuxt-link in Nuxt. Thank you